# Reducing the need for xsl:if and code duplications

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XSLT code that differs only by a single class element. However, all of the internal div content.

I attempted to separate out the starting tag as such:

```
 <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <div class="position first">

 </xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
        <div class="position">
  </xsl:if>
```

But ofcourse it produces invalid XSLT code. [The DIV's must be closed within their scope].

Is there another way to add the optional class keyword without have to reduplicate the internal contents?

Comment: Please, when asking XSLT questions, tell us whether you want an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 solution. The answer is often different in the two cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="position">
   <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">position first</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:if>    
</div>
```

The `xsl:attribute` instruction should override the literal attribute.

Comment: That is the kind of thing I've been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xsl:choose`. A sample template is given below

```
<xsl:template match="div">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">position first</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="concat('position', position())"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your suggestion. Are you suggesting that a separate XSL template for just the DIV?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative way you can do this without duplicating the use of the "position" class in your XSLT:

```
<div class="position{substring(' first', 1, 6 * (position() = 1))}">
    <!-- Whatever goes inside the div -->
</div>
```

And you can do this even more cleanly in XSLT 2.0:

```
<div class="position{if (position() = 1) then ' first' else ''}">
    <!-- Whatever goes inside the div -->
</div>
```